# Generalizable etched line effect with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to develop a generalizable solution for creating etched lines. The goal is to be able to not have to manually pick closely related colors for every color scheme where I want etching. The issue seems that the color of the indented part in relation to the color of the background is somewhat critical for creating the 3 dimensional effect.

[Below is an example in blue (the lines above the comment bubble/underneath the number "11")](http://instagram.com/p/Omjwtpxm_O/). I think I need to use `box-shadow` but not sure if this is the best way.

If box-shadow is what I should use, does anyone know how to set its CSS values such that would would work for say a gray line would also work for say a blue line?

[image]

Comment: You mean this : border-bottom: 1px solid #1C5380; ? I suggest that you inspect the element to find the proper CSS.

Comment: thanks @Vucko, i'm interested in a generalizable solution that could be applied irrespective of color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use borders with semi-transparent black/white colors (*using `rgba`*) that will darken/lighten the underlying color.

Example at http://dabblet.com/gist/4182495

Adding pseudo elements with `:after`/`:before` gives you extra power in adding second level borders etc..

Comment: -@Gaby, i'm realizing that the border is all the way around and simply changing `border:` to `border-top:` doesn't work so well. Can you take a shot at just making a bottom or top border.

Comment: @timpeterson, not sure what you mean.. the border is all around indeed. Although just for the first element. the `.etched:first-child(2n)` targets all but the first element, and there i have `border-top:0` which removes the top border for those elements.

Comment: sorry to be unclear. I mean that I'm only interested in having the etched border on the bottom or top. I would be interested in having no border at all on the left or right sides.

Comment: ok, have a look at http://dabblet.com/gist/4183652 i split the `border:` to two properties `border-top:` and `border-bottom:`. And again we disable the `border-top` for all but the first element.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the slightly simplified CSS for that comment indicator, which I found using the Chrome Web Developer tools:

```
.media-bar .count-badge {
    padding: 0 7px;
    background: #1C5380;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 12px;
}
```

If you visit the page and inspect the count-badge element, you'll be able to turn the box-shadow styles on and off, which will show how they create the inset effect.

Comment: -@Douglas, thanks can you add to your answer/comment on the generalizablity of your solution if someone wanted to use a different color scheme other than blue?

Comment: The box shadow colours used are black and white, which will darken and brighten whatever they appear against, so it is quite general. To be fully general, you'd want to consider using [Lab colour space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space), but then you'll have to calculate the shadow colours and opacities for each background colour. Black and white is a good approximation.

Comment: Hi Douglas, the CSS in your answer looks like it is for the oval badge and **not** the line below it which is what I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are two borders together:

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #1C5380;
border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
```